# How can I solve my issue relating to parameterless constructor when using generics with constraint defined

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, interface, .net-core, generic-interface

I have a class that i try to create dependency injection for in my `StartUp.cs` file, like this

```
services.AddTransient<IContextFactory<BlogPostContext>, ContextFactory<BlogPostContext>>();
```

I also try to pass the the `IContextFactory` into a constructor like this

`public BlogPostRepository(IContextFactory<BlogPostContext> blogPostContext)`

but I get errors on the lines above stating that

> 'BlogPostContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public
>   parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'IContextFactory'

I am not sure why because I am using `new T()` as a constraint in my interface declaration.

**Here is the class I am trying to instantiate**

```
public class BlogPostContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDatabase;
    private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;

    public IMongoCollection<BlogPostModel> BlogPostModelCollection => _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BlogPostModel>("BlogPostModel");

    public BlogPostContext(IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase, IOptions<MongoDbSettings> settings)
    {
        _mongoDatabase = mongoDatabase;
        _mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
        if (null != _mongoDatabase) _mongoDatabase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
    }
}
```

**Generic interface and it's concrete implementation**

```
namespace FloormindCore.Blog.Factory
{
    public interface IContextFactory<out T> where T : new()
    {
        T Create();
    }
}

using System;

namespace FloormindCore.Blog.Factory
{
    public class ContextFactory<T> : IContextFactory<T> where T : new()
    {
        public T Create()

        {
            return  (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but your class `BlogPostContext` does not have parameter less constructor.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why have the factory in the first place. There may be a possible code smell here. Your `BlogPostContext` has explicit dependencies. Why then are you placing a constraint on the factory for the parameter-less constructors.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says : as per constraint, compiler is expecting `BlogPostContext` with parameter less constructor. Adding below parameter less constructor to `BlogPostContext` should resolve the error

```
public BlogPostContext(){}
```

**As an additional note:** To me it looks like you need to inject other dependencies as well into `BlogPostContext`, so why define `T : new()` constraint in first place. Shouldn't you be injecting the concrete implementation for other constructor parameters as well in your start up.